# Manual transaction management in DBD::Pg

Tags: perl, postgresql, dbi, dbd-pg

I'm having a hard time getting manual transactions to work as documented in DBD::Pg, or I'm simply misunderstanding said documentation.

My understanding is that if I want to manually manage transactions, I should turn off AutoCommit.

```
$dbh->{AutoCommit} = 0;
$dbh->begin_work;
```

But when I do this, I get continual errors

```
DBD::Pg::db begin_work failed: Already in a transaction
```

To get this to work, I need to turn on AutoCommit first.

```
$dbh->{AutoCommit} = 1;
$dbh->begin_work;
```

But that doesn't seem to agree with any of the documentation.

Am I simply misunderstanding it?

Comment: That does all seem rather odd. Can you show a complete test case and give your DBI and DBD::Pg versions?

Answer (score 4):

> My understanding is that if I want to manually manage transactions, I should turn off AutoCommit.

No, quite the opposite. Setting `AutoCommit` to `0` starts a transaction, so you want to set it to `1`. To have your changes committed automatically (`AutoCommit => 1`) is to have the database not use transactions, which is the opposite of what you want.

Comment: Seems rather unintuitive. Turn on autocommit, so I'm able to then start a manual transaction.

Comment: To be fair, it only makes sense once you realise autocommit=0 sends a BEGIN for you

Answer (score 4):

> My understanding is that if I want to manually manage transactions, I should turn off AutoCommit.

Correct.

However, DBD::Pg automatically starts your transactions for you.  You can't start the transactions manually.  Your best option is to leave autocommit off and then just do:

```
 $dbh->commit;
```

when you are ready to commit.  This will both commit the existing transaction and start a new transaction.

Now if you set autocommit to on, then anything that exists outside of a transaction becomes its own transaction, one transaction per *statement.*  If you want to be assured of manually managing transactions, you want to set it off.